# Filter Alert Javascript, how to

Tags: javascript, filter, alert

i saw this code some time ago, and i was planning to list the hrefs of a website, but now i want to filter it

```
 var arr = [], l = document.links;
 for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
   arr.push(l[i].href);
 }
 alert(arr);
```

i need this code to display links that contains only a certain text in it

for example show in alert only links that contains in the `href` ....?
`day=20, ?day=22, and ?day=25`

i tried to add one if before .push, but nothing worked, only showed a blank alert :(

last thing, if in the place of alert i want it to open in a new tab each link, someone can give me direction or the simplest way ;)

Comment: Can you show your attempt with an `if` ? There was probably an easy to fix bug.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `if (l[i].href.indexOf("TEXT HERE")) {` of some sort, but you should show your attempts

Comment: my attemp was adding 
if(/?day=20/?day=22/?day=25/) {

before the arr.push
...

Comment: Ian, i tried this: 
var arr = [], l = document.links;
 for(var i=0; i<l.length; i++) {
     if (l[i].href.indexOf("day=22")) {
   arr.push(l[i].href);
     }
 }

still showing all the hrefs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern browsers you can do this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="day"]');
```

That will give you an NodeList of link elements that contain `day` in the `href`. Then you can filter like this to get the `hrefs` in an array:

```
var hrefs = Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(link){
  return link.href;
});
```

Comment: There was a typo it's `prototype`. Works fine for me, check here http://jsbin.com/axisih/1/edit